# Bootstrap 3 grid display issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well the first thing to tell is that I am a newbie in web programming so I might have an easy issue for you all or not.

The thing is that I am trying to put 2 elements one next to the other using the following structure based on the well-known grid system of Bootstrap3:

```
<div class="container presentation">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6 stitched">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 stitched">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The *stitched* class you see is a CSS effect found on the internet that makes the element look like it's really stitched. The CSS code is the following:

```
.stitched{
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 background: #ff0030;
 color: #fff;
 /*font-size: 21px;*/
 /*font-weight: bold;*/
 line-height: 1.3em;
 border: 2px dashed #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ff0030, 2px 1px 3px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
 text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
 /*font-weight: normal;*/
}
```

So the problem is this. When I see the page, those both elements aren't one next to the other, in fact, the second div is under the first and there is no way to display both divs inline. Only when I remove the *margin* property from the CSS I manage to display both one next to the other, however they look horrible since they overlap. Does anyone understand why is this happening? And of course anyone knows how can I display both elements inline without making them overlap?

Thanks. (I'll provide pics if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in bootstrap have specific requirements about margin and border size.  If you put your stitched `div`s inside the columns `div`s then it should work. Like this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8zk5r/))

```
<div class="container presentation">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class='stitched'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class='stitched'>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked to me. I used your structure and it was awesome. I guess I know why. Creating a div inside de "col-lg-6" makes it look ok and since has you said, if I write col-lg-6 and stitched in the same tag I modigy the default column properties. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with bootstrap 3 yet but assuming it works on the same principle of bootstrap 2, a grid layout can only contain a maximum of 12 columns. You are using 6 and 6 here which add up to 12 which is great. However, you are then adding additional margins which pushes your layout over the 12 column threshold causing the div to drop below and grid system to break.

See here for information regarding the grid system. It's pretty well explained:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

To solve your issue, you need to contain your stitched divs inside the columns divs and avoid adding in additional margins unless you compensate by removing these elsewhere in your template.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using `.col-lg-6` which only works for resolutions of >= 1200px. By good practice, if you are only going to define one class in the cols, use `.col-sm-x` which works for all displays >= 768px. To be extra sure, you can define your class as `.col-cs-6 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-6` to make sure it'll be the same across all devices if thats what you are going for.

I got it working. See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pdBDM/

See [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) for a better explanation than mine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @jason-sperske provided the best solution. You can look at the structure of his code. However I found your comment useful. Thanks

Comment: My code structure is the same as his except i account for all screen resolutions not just those above `lg`.

Comment: Yep thanks to your comment I realized the difference between just putting lg or adding md and so on. Thank you so much.